# .NET Core and Azure Active Directory integration

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using the token authentication (instead of cookie) with Azure Active Directory.

Based on this article: https://www.itunity.com/article/angular-2-openid-connect-azure-active-directory-3093

I was able to get it working on the client side.

```js
   public validateSignature(token): Observable<boolean> {
        /* Retrieve from federated metadata endpoint.
        In this sample, the document was downloaded locally */
        return this.httpService.get("metadata/metadata.xml")
            .map((res: Response) => {
                let dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(res.text(), "text/xml");
                let json = xml2json(dom, "");
                let cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" + 
                JSON.parse(json).EntityDescriptor[0]["ds:Signature"]
                    ["KeyInfo"]["X509Data"]["X509Certificate"] + 
                 "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
                 let key = KEYUTIL.getKey(cert);
                return KJUR.jws.JWS.verifyJWT(token, key, { alg: ['RS256'] });
            })
        }
```

I was trying to re-implement the above method in the .NET Core 1.0.3.

Based on this article: [how to sign and verify signature with net and a certificate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c/)

The following line won't compile on .NET Core:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
```

I am not sure what is correct way to verify the token based on the certificate in .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to verify the token issued by Azure AD is leverage the OWIN comment with web API. We just need to config the `JwtBearerOptions` and send the request to a controller which protected by Azure AD. If the token is not verified, you will get the 401 response. You can refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore).

And if you want to implement the code to verify the token manually, we can refer the code how the Microsoft verify the token in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer).

I also wrote a code sample for your reference:

```
public class JsonWebTokenValidator
{
    public void Validate(string token)
    {
        var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        var options = new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            ConfigurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever()),

            TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/",

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "{audience}",

                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            },
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
        };

        SecurityToken validatedToken = null;
        ClaimsPrincipal result = null;
        var configuration = options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(new CancellationToken()).Result;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys = configuration.SigningKeys;

        options.ConfigurationManager.RequestRefresh();
        foreach (var validators in options.SecurityTokenValidators)
        {
            result = validators.ValidateToken(token, options.TokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
        }

        foreach (var claim in result.Claims)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Subject}:{claim.Value}");
        }
    }
```

Project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.9",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },

    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": {
      "version": "5.1.3"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols": "2.1.3",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect": "2.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @DerekLiang If it is helpful for the issue, please mark it as the answer so that the community who have the same issue can recognize the helpful post easily:)

Comment: I see the ValidateIssuerSigningKey set to true, but there is not signing key. When I add a SymmetricSecurityKey value to the IssuerSigningKey property is works no mater what value is given. I was assuming that it would only validate for the secret key that I have.

Answer (score 0):

According to this QA: [implement RSA in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986995/implement-rsa-in-net-core) your `cert` object should have a `GetRSAPublicKey()` method which returns an `RSA` object - just be sure to wrap it in `using` as it's `IDisposable`.

```
static bool Verify(string text, byte[] signature, string certPath)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2( certPath );

    using( RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey() )
    using( SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed() )
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes( text );
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash( data );

        return rsa.VerifyHash( hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature );
    }
}
```

Apparently `GetRSAPublicKey()` is defined as an extension method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsapublickey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In the original question, what is the data to be verified? The id_token has 3 parts, header, claims and signature delimited by '.'. And also  CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1") is not available in .NET Core.