# Get a list of groups that Azure AD user belongs to in claims for .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the list of groups in Azure AD user belongs to in .Net Core with token generated in the "implicit flow". There is no group information.

I am using "implicit flow" as mentioned in the following link:
[.NET Core and Azure Active Directory integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272287/net-core-and-azure-active-directory-integration)

The following shows how to do it in the .NET Framework but .NET Core don't have the 'ActiveDirectoryClient' class.

[Get a list of groups that Azure AD user belongs to in claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343369/get-a-list-of-groups-that-azure-ad-user-belongs-to-in-claims)

Any Help is much appreciated!

derek

Answer (score 5):

You could firstly set the `groupMembershipClaims` property to `SecurityGroup` in manifest , then get the groups list in asp.net core after login :

```
var groups = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "groups").ToList();
```

Update :

Then you could call Azure AD Graph api to get the group information . Firstly refer to code sample :https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

In .net core app , you could get the group object id and call graph api :

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/<objectid>?api-version=1.6
```

You could set `Read all groups` delegated permission for `Windows Azure Active Directory` in `Required permissions` blade of your app . Then try below code to get the group name :

```
        try
        {

            var groups = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "groups").ToList();


            string userObjectID = (User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, HttpContext.Session));
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.ClientId, Startup.ClientSecret);
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Startup.GraphResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

            //
            // Retrieve the group information.
            //
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/"+ groups[1].Value + "?api-version=1.6" );
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<Dictionary<String, String>> responseElements = new List<Dictionary<String, String>>();
                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                String responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString);
                var groupName = model.displayName;
            }
            else
            {

                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }
```

Group entity below is for your reference :

```
   public class RootObject
        {
            public string objectType { get; set; }
            public string objectId { get; set; }
            public object deletionTimestamp { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public object dirSyncEnabled { get; set; }
            public string displayName { get; set; }
            public object mail { get; set; }
            public string mailNickname { get; set; }
            public bool mailEnabled { get; set; }
            public bool securityEnabled { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: The problem was that the claims don't include the group information. You need to make a second call as demonstrated in the second link above.

Comment: yes, group claim only return group object id and not group name , you need to call graph api to get the group information like name .  Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: NaiveSessionCache is part of System.IdentityModel that does not work with Core. Is there another option?