RSA Decrypt "Access Denied"
I'm working in .NET 6 trying to decrypt the subscription notification received from graph api.
 X509Certificate2 cert = new(pfxData, "pass"); //pfxfile as bytearray
 var rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
 byte[] encryptedSymmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String("dataKey"); //Datakey from graph api
 byte[] decryptedSymmetricKey = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedSymmetricKey, fOAEP: true); //Exception here

The fOAEP didn't work (build error) so changed that to RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256. Now i get the "Access Denied" error.
byte[] decryptedSymmetricKey = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedSymmetricKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

Exception:
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Access denied.'

I'm in need of the decryptsymmetickey to get the data from graph api payload.
Any help?
Tried,
1.
var newKey =  rsa.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
 RSA rsa1 = RSA.Create();

 rsa1.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(newKey, out _);
rsa1.Decrypt(.....) //Same Exception


The SO solution from RSA decrypt throws 'Access denied' exception

My KeyUsage showed AllUsages so it should do the decryption as well. I tried the reset like this
var rsa3 = ResetKeyUsage(((RSACng)rsa1).Key) 
rsa3.Decrypt() //The key doesn't have the decrypt method

and the key returned doesn't have the decrypt method. Not sure if i tried in the right way.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-with-resource-data?tabs=csharp

Which line throws the exception, and what is the exact error message?

@canton7 Updated the question, the error is thrown in the rsa.Decrypt line

Could this be related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51993985/1086121

Which .NET version are you running? Is it possible to export the private key via rsa.ExportPkcs8PrivateKeyPem() if an X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable is passed as the third parameter when creating the X509Certificate2 instance?

@canton7 I don't have a CNG key and not sure of that implementation. Any idea?

@Topaco .Net 6, and still unclear of the solution to decryptKey

@ACoder As in, export and re-import the key

Have you tried the suggested approach (on .NET 6 with e.g. ExportPkcs8PrivateKey())?

@Topaco Yes, that gave me a new key and what am i supposed to do with that?

Create a new RSA instance, import the exported key with ImportPkcs8PrivateKey() and try the decryption again.

@Topaco Tried, same exception. Updated in the question

I cannot reproduce this on .NET 6. Base64 encode the key and load it into an ASN.1/DER parser (e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/, has also an offline version). What is the OID? Compare with other keys.

Also unclear: I don't have a CNG key. What kind of key do you have?

@Topaco My KeyUsage shows AllUsages and still i get the "Access Denied" exception. I tried the reset like this var rsa3 = ResetKeyUsage(((RSACng)rsa1).Key) and the key returned doesn't have the decrypt method. Any help?

Did you analyze the exported key with an ASN.1 parser?

Not sure what that is and you mean the CNG key?

I already described it here (key refers to the key exported with ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()).

AsnReader parser = new(newKey, AsnEncodingRules.DER) Checked, no errors. The HasData flag is true with the RuleSet is DER

I am trying to find out if the problem is caused by the key or your environment. Please run the code linked here in your environment. Is the decryption successful in your environment?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Works fine for me, see if you can join the chat. "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

@Topaco can you join the chat ?

@Topaco The code works with my key when the encrypt part has the string value like in code. But in the actual scenario i pass in the DataKey from the graphiAPI response and that gives me "Parameter Incorrect" exception. I pass as this Convert.FromBase64String(payload.DataKey). Any idea?

Too little information for an analysis. Du you mean this code https://dotnetfiddle.net/LqPOIF? If not, provide a link. Where is the exception thrown? Is Convert.FromBase64String(payload.DataKey) really ASN.1/DER encoded? How big is your RSA key, 2048 bits?

as per the code in https://dotnetfiddle.net/LqPOIF . Exception is thrown in the line byte[] encryptedSymmetricKey = rsaNew.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload.DataKey), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256); Not sure what type of the key i get, but its not ASN.1, i tried with the decoder and it showed error "Length over 48 bits not supported at position 1"

The question about ASN.1/DER encoding was a misunderstanding on my part. I had forgotten that encryptedSymmetricKey is an AES key encrypted with RSA. How many bytes is encryptedSymmetricKey and how big is your RSA key (size of the modulus, typically 2048 bits)?

Also, I don't understand why you call rsaNew.Encrypt(), since you want to decrypt, i.e. you would have to call rsaNew.Decrypt().

Tried that first, it throws "Parameter Incorrect" exception for that in the rsaNew.Decrypt() line. Is it then the payload.DataKey i receive from graph API is the issue?

Since you cannot provide any test data, please answer at least the questions so that the necessary criteria can be tested. So: How many bytes is encryptedSymmetricKey and how big is your RSA key? Also keep in mind to preface your comments with @Topaco, otherwise I won't receive a notification.

If both have identical lengths, the exception indicates that the ciphertext cannot be decrypted with the RSA key, e.g. wrong RSA key, corrupted message, or wrong padding/padding parameter.

@Topaco encryptedSymmetricKey - byte[256],  i.e encryptedSymmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(payload.DataKey) RSA key - byte[1231]

Regarding the key, you have given the wrong value. Which value is in brackets before the modulus (the modulus is the value above the public exponent 65537)? Presumably it says 2048 bit, so that key and ciphertext are at least consistent in terms of their lengths. I have already mentioned the reasons why decryption then fails: Wrong key for this ciphertext (then find out why), corrupted data (then find out where this happens), the padding or the padding parameters are not correct (then choose other digests for OAEP or try PKCS#1 v1.5, or better ask the other side).

@Topaco I have a small clarification here. In this var rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() the rsa size is 2048 and in this line var exportedKey =  rsa.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey() the exportedKey size is 1231. So now i have to check the certificate that is generated which may have the issue basically, right?

You could have easily determined the key size with the (offline) ASN.1 parser (as described above). But it looks like you have a 2048 bits key and a 256 byte ciphertext, which is consistent.

I can't answer why the decryption fails without test data, I listed a few possibilities: E.g. the public key used for encryption may not match the private key in the pfx file used for decryption. A different padding or other OAEP parameters may have been used during encryption. You need to clarify this with the other side.

@Topaco Okay, i'll look on the other side as you mentioned. Thank you
