# DotNetCore: Generate RSA Private/Public keys

Tags: .net-core, rsa

I have to convert below dotnet framework code to generate RSA public and private keys in dotnet core.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
string publicKey = RSA.ToXmlString(false);
string privateKey = RSA.ToXmlString(true);
```

ABove Code is not supported in Dotnet Core and throw below error:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.PlatformNotSupportedException An
>   unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'
>   occurred in System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll: 'Operation is
>   not supported on this platform.'    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.ToXmlString(Boolean
>   includePrivateParameters)

Solution:Below extension worked for me

```
public static class RSACryptoServiceProviderExtensions
    {
         public static void ToXmlFile(this RSA rsa, bool includePrivateParameters, string xmlFilePath)  
        {  
            RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters);  
            File.WriteAllText(xmlFilePath,  
                string.Format("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>{0}</Modulus><Exponent>{1}</Exponent><P>{2}</P><Q>{3}</Q><DP>{4}</DP><DQ>{5}</DQ><InverseQ>{6}</InverseQ><D>{7}</D></RSAKeyValue>",  
                  parameters.Modulus != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Modulus) : null,  
                  parameters.Exponent != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Exponent) : null,  
                  parameters.P != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.P) : null,  
                  parameters.Q != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Q) : null,  
                  parameters.DP != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.DP) : null,  
                  parameters.DQ != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.DQ) : null,  
                  parameters.InverseQ != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.InverseQ) : null,  
                  parameters.D != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.D) : null)  
                  );  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: `ToXmlString` is not supported in .NET Core (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23686)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` is not recommended. I think you can still use it with package [System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/) installed.

Another way is to use `RSA` base class, refering to [implement RSA in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986995/implement-rsa-in-net-core):

**.NET Core**

```cs
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.KeySize = desiredKeySizeInBits;

    // when the key next gets used it will be created at that keysize.
    DoStuffWithThePrivateKey(rsa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do with *RSACryptoServiceProvider*. You may try with below code in .NET Core.

**.NET Core**

```
public static string GeneratePEM(RSA rsa, bool includePrivateParameters = false)
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = includePrivateParameters ? rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey() : rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey();
        var builder = new StringBuilder($"-----BEGIN RSA {(includePrivateParameters ? "PRIVATE" : "PUBLIC")} KEY");
        builder.AppendLine("-----");

        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(keyBytes);
        var offset = 0;
        const int LINE_LENGTH = 64;

        while (offset < base64String.Length)
        {
            var lineEnd = Math.Min(offset + LINE_LENGTH, base64String.Length);
            builder.AppendLine(base64String.Substring(offset, lineEnd - offset));
            offset = lineEnd;
        }

        builder.Append($"-----END RSA {(includePrivateParameters ? "PRIVATE" : "PUBLIC")} KEY");
        builder.AppendLine("-----");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```