# How to determine if RSA base class has public or private key?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa

I have an RSA base class that has been initialized using ImportParameters. In some cases only the public key will be loaded. How can I determine if the given RSA object is populated with only public key, or populated with the private key? RSACryptoServiceProvider provided a IsPublicOnly (or similar method).

As per ([implement RSA in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986995/implement-rsa-in-net-core)), I have switch from RSACryptoServiceProvider to RSA base class which has resolved runtime exceptions when hosted in an Azure app service.

Comment: Interesting, I don't see any good way to do this. You could always attempt to `ExportParameters(true)` and catch the Exception to indicate a public-key only instance.

Comment: I'd rather create a signature and catch the exception there than to expose the private key.

Comment: The real question is why do you want to know? If it’s so you can create a signature, or decrypt, just try those operations and they’ll fail if there’s no private key.

Answer (score 0):

I use this.
Have a nice day

```
public class RsaEncryption
{
private readonly RSA _rsa;
public bool IsPublicKeyOnly { get; set; }

public byte[] PublicKey { get { return _rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey(); } }
public byte[] PrivateKey { get { return _rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey(); } }

public RsaEncryption(Sizes keySize = Sizes.Size2048)
{
    _rsa = RSA.Create((int)keySize);
}

public RsaEncryption(byte[] key)
{
    _rsa = RSA.Create();
    
    try
    {
        _rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(key, out int bytesRead);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException)
    {
        try
        {
            _rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(key, out int bytesRead);
            IsPublicKeyOnly = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public string Encrypt(string text)
{
    byte[] toEncrypt = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(_rsa.Encrypt(toEncrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));
}

public string Decrypt(string cipher)
{
    if(IsPublicKeyOnly)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The private key is needed for decrypt data");
    }

    byte[] toDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher);
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(_rsa.Decrypt(toDecrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**